# Magento 1.9 Get only default items from options of a bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I have a bundle product that have different options, and each options have different items. How can I get only a list of **default items** and it's **Default Qty** of those options, programmatically.

See the screen shot, I only want to get **Sku 020524** and **Sku 020592**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get this data in a report format?

Comment: I got it fixed. But no, not in a report format. I just want to retrieve the information and output it to the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(bundle_pruduct_id);
$selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product
);
$bundled_items = array();
foreach($selectionCollection as $option) {
    if ($option->is_default) {
       $bundled_items[] = array(
           'id' => $option->product_id,
           'name' => $option->name,
           'qty'=> $option->selection_qty,
       );
    }

}
print_r($bundled_items);
```